# spread operator is not working ,might be because of my usage,help me to figure it out

Tags: reactjs

the output of the code is
[image]

this is the code,here i am passing an array to this react function,

```
const Lifeofgame = arrayarg=> {
    const result = ([...arrayarg]);
    const  tempstatuslist = ([...arrayarg]);
    console.log("the props values are inside log inside templist is");
    console.log(tempstatuslist);
    result[0][2]=true;
    console.log(`result is ${result} tempstatuslist is ${tempstatuslist}`);
}
```

here the function gets an array(matrix) as an argument. then copies the values of that argument to two diff variables using the spread operator.on updating one value, the other is also getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructing two-dimensional array doesn't copy Array to a new variable.
It copies the address of each child array and merges them into a new array, so when you change one value, it changes the original array.
You can fix this in this way

```
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayarg));
```